# How to list an old-style university degree with a modern Bologna-style degree in a CV?

Tags: resume, europe

On a standard CV template, the "education field" for someone who has an engineering degree, usually looks like this:

```
MSc in XXX, University X, 2010-2012
BSc in XXX, University X, 2007-2010
```

In the Bologna System, a Bachelor degree is not a full engineering degree. For that a masters degree is also required.

However, I completed a full 5 year engineering degree in an Eastern European country, where the system was not yet split into the "bachelor" and "master" levels, and in practice included the courses of both. I would be legally allowed to call myself an engineer even without having completed a masters degree.

After that, to gather more experience, I completed a masters program in a Western European country.

What would be the best way to list both of them, without having to "downgrade" my original degree to a BSC one, and without having to spend too many words explaining it?

Comment: Is there a governing body in your country that accredits Engineers? For example: in my jurisdiction, [EGBC](https://www.egbc.ca) is responsible for accrediting engineers and geoscientists.

Comment: I just list mine as a single Master's (which s the closet to my actual degree at the time) since I technically only have one piece of paper. If it's more than 5 years ago, no one cares anyway.

Answer (score 9):

If the 5-year Eastern European engineering degree is equivalent to an MSc according to some official scale, then I'd be inclined to list it as:

*"Engineering Degree (combined BSc and MSc), University X, 2007-2012."*

There really aren't many ways to misinterpret that, since it is emphatic that it is a 5-year course in engineering and that the final level achieved is MSc, and if anyone asks further questions I can't imagine it taking too many words to answer.

The additional MSc from a Western European should of course also be listed.

Comment: If one holds a masters in engineering I am not sure if matters how one breaks up their education, they hold both a BSc and MSc in Engineering. One must not try and claim they have two MSc degrees of course unless that actually is the case. Combined Masters programs with an undergraduate exist in the Western world (granted they are technically separate allowing the student to graduate with an undergraduate degree at any time after it’s completed)

Comment: @Donald, I think the crucial point is that the OP *doesn't* hold a separate BSc (because of the difference of systems), but wants to present the information in a way that doesn't cause confusion to anyone who is generally familiar with the Western system. I think a parenthetical remark of "combined BSc and MSc" leaves no room for any kind of adverse confusion about the absence of a BSc being listed, and at 4 words is the least that can be said.

Comment: I assume 'Engineering Degree' refers to the title of the actual degree OP holds (for example in Germany that could be Engineering Diploma). One could also add 'equivalent to' combined BSc and MSc in the bracket.